# Looping for copying information from one column to the next in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a dataframe like below:

```
test
#  Name1 Name2  Match
#1     A     C      1
#2     E     NA     0
#3     D     G      1
#4     R     NA     0
```

The match column shows 1 if both name columns have a non-NA element, and 0 when they don't. I'd like to create a way to read through a dataframe so that if test$match == 0, then the row element from Name 1 will be copied over to Name 2 to look like:

```
test
#  Name1 Name2  Match
#1     A     C      1
#2     E     E      0 #I don't care about the match column after the change
#3     D     G      1
#4     R     R      0
```

I've been trying to create a for loop with an if statement, but it simply removes the Name2 column.

```
test$Name2 <- for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  if (test$match == 0) {
      test$Name2[i] <- test$Name1[i]
    }
}
```

If there's a way to accomplish this without a for loop I'd be particularly interested in that as the dataset is large.

Comment: Scrap the `match` column and use the `dplyr` package: `test %>% mutate(Name2 = coalesce(Name2, Name1))`.  I assume here that you **don't** want to overwrite a normal `Name2` (like `"B"`) with an `NA` from `Name1`.  If you **do**, then `test %>% mutate(Name2 = if_else(is.na(Name1) | is.na(Name2), Name1, Name2))` should work.

Comment: It works on my personal device, thank you. For security purposes though my employer has certain restrictions on packages that can be downloaded to a work computer, and dplyr is one of them. Do you perhaps know a way I could accomplish this with something from the apply family, or with basic R?

Comment: Probably `df$Name2 <- mapply(FUN = function(n1, n2){if(is.na(n1) || is.na(n2)){n1}else{n2}}, test$Name1, test$Name2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)`

Comment: @Greg: The request was for an efficient method. Your use fo `if(){}else{}` inside an `mapply` loop is a classic example of how NOT to achieve efficiency when using R.

Comment: @IRTFM Technically, the request was for *"a way to accomplish this without a for loop"* or [*"with something from the **apply family**"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134040/looping-for-copying-information-from-one-column-to-the-next-in-r#comment120423296_68134040). We could easily vectorize this condition with `test$Name2 <- ifelse(is.na(test$Name1) | is.na(test$Name2), test$Name1, test$Name2)` all without the need for a `Match` column in the first place.

Comment: ‘mapply’ is just a for-loop equivalent. And ifelse isn’t real R vectorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in base R quite easily. Use logical indexing on both sides to set first col values into 2nd col when `match ==0`

```
test[ test$Match == 0, "Name2"] <- test[ test$Match == 0, "Name1"]
```

This is a vectorized operation and likely to be much more efficient than looping operations that use `if` conditional operation. The logical indexing creates a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs as long as the match column. The result is that the rows with FALSEs for that match will simply remain untouched. Conversely the TRUE values for the comparison on the RHS will construct a vector of replacements that will be filled in order on the LHS of the assignment.

If you wanted to skip the creation of Match think about:

```
test$Name2[is.na(Name2)] <- test$Name1[is.na(test$Name2)]
```

... which you would "read" as "replace any missing value in Name2 with the Name1 value on the same row.